# Is there an efficient algorithm to check whether a matrix is symmetrizable using only permutation matrix?

Tags: algorithms, m-matrix

Is there any known efficient algorithm (something that works better than brute-force algorithm) to check that given a $(0,1)$-$d \times d$ matrix $A$, is there a permutation matrix $P$ of the same size such that $PA$ is a symmetric matrix? I believe this question might have been done in the past (probably even for a more general matrix), however I can not find any literature that is connected to this problem.

Comment: Bhat, Kabekode VS. "An algorithm for matrix symmetrization." Journal of the Franklin Institute 312.1 (1981): 89-93.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is NP-complete, see C. Colbourn and B. D. McKay, A correction to Colbourn's paper on the complexity of matrix symmetrizability, Information Processing Letters, 11 (1980) 96-97. [Here is a scan](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/ColbournMcKaySymmetrizability.pdf).

Interestingly, if we ask instead whether there is a permutation matrix $P$ such that $PA$ is the transpose of $A$, that is equivalent to the graph isomorphism problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved via ILP by treating elements of $P$ as binary variables with constraints:
$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{i=1}^d P_{i,j} = 1 & \forall j\in[d],\\
\sum_{j=1}^d P_{i,j} = 1 & \forall i\in[d],\\
\sum_{k=1}^d P_{i,k}A_{k,j} = \sum_{k=1}^d P_{j,k}A_{k,i} & \forall i,j \in[d],\ i<j.
\end{cases}
$$

Here is a [sample Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNU12L2zAQfDf4PyzcQ6TUF-LXgzwfR-Pio30oCSEo9ibZxJaCJDuXlv73rux80dK7CgxG2pkd7YweoFbe0hs4-oFxpGEC6TiO4ugBNqjRKo-gwCpdmhrcqa6RqwvQ8J2_cfrYo-MoY2DW_YvZLNGJlnG0NhYISAf4BoWWT3EEvML-7rZPn9LLSVjZnJLdItDNdwmFn9CdtBfjJJW9tF5PdYID2rphidYcHZg1ZHF0YMTXi9Bna5oDdx71iCVWWCNTybPieUXOi4Mg-ZjCVa9IRyMtZfK06NspOFizYigfOq90gZABOSgs8nzKBCr0AwfaHMHbE3gDzlQtAvkeX-KaNM9Rw8s0v3DFUU1VEJvRG5Yv2uMG7ZTrlM2t2VhVi57GTgbP0_zzAGQPGTn0S7PaYeGpRQFfDHOfB9PPQ3ky-mIsq1kh363RZRzl3K_j0HhctsqSYiliRVrZ0-SbbfAd2zqcKstlYXgKVgVLwDUsM58L9kwu_nRWS5Aw4UQFeR9SsNsfUIQb3pAOqD4YR3oDfqs85MPOlGtI_z-A9_F7TyIl-wUMOTVif73u_m-t5-rdXTX9o7q7VG9qsDrk8vX2kuAnPc1mopV9NJM2oLvqDUegVVWDTuRyRB5rJ-Svawosq-ah4OV9lOcwJHDcUrEFtzVNVYZc3E1LOYfWg3gdZkzpltejoKqj7I5-A7irS7I=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that constructs a random symmetric $01$-matrix of a given, randomly permutes its rows, and then tries to find a suitable $P$ that would permute it back into a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For many NP-complete problems, there is a heuristic algorithm that solves the problem in most cases. For NP-complete optimization problems, there is often a heuristic algorithm that gives a nearly optimal solution. These heuristic algorithms are often evolutionary algorithms or simulated annealing algorithms that either minimize or maximize some function.

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any matrix norm, and if $g$ is a permutation, then let $\phi(g)$ denote its corresponding permutation matrix. Given a matrix $A$, define a loss function $L_A:S_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by letting $L_A(g)$ by letting $L_A(\phi(g))=\|\phi(g)A-(\phi(g)A)^T\|$.

The goal is to minimize the loss function $L_A$ through evolutionary computation or simulated annealing, and once one has $L_A(g)=0$, the matrix $\phi(g)A$ is symmetric. In these algorithms, one wants to mutate a permutation $g$ by replacing the permutation $g$ with $(a,b)\circ g$ where $(a,b)$ is a randomly selected transposition.